Select by Location on multiple layers using ArcGIS Pro
I want to Select By Location with multiple layers.
For example, I want to select parcels where it has turbines, routes, and roads in them. The select by location only allows for one to be done at a time. Is there a work around to do all of them?
I am using ArcGIS Pro.

You run the tool 3 times, but you change the selection type on subsequent runs to ADD TO SELECTION. It's in the help file.
